# Cannot select brush stroke handles separately

Tags: brushes

I am trying to make a Y shaped crease. I am following a tutorial that is using an older version of Blender (2.79) and I am using version 3.0.

In the tutorial, the speaker uses the crease brush, opens the stroke methods, picks curve and draws 3 points to form the "V" section of the letter Y then proceeds to select the central handle of the point at the bottom of the "V" and then places a point at the bottom to form the vertical limb of the letter Y.

When I try to do the same, selecting the central handle (denoted by a red triangle on the UI), it selects all the handles of that point (the red triangle and the 2 green squares on each side) and when I try to place a point to draw the vertical limb of the letter Y, it forms a weird curve rather than a straight new limb from that central point.

I want to select the central handle alone (or do something else if the differrent versions do it differently) to allow me to add a new point in a separate line that branches from the original curves.

I have included two gifs to explain what I mean

Thank you all for your time

[image: tutorial]

[image: my go at it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what he is doing is he is adding another control point at the bottom of the V before extruding it as an Y :

[image]

If you watch the video closely, you will see that he adds an extra stroke to the second branch of the V so he can extrude it for the tail later.

I guess Blender's stroke curve doesn't support curves with loose parts so it may be the only way.

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> to add a new control point each time, [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/sculpt_paint/stroke_curve.html) is the official documentation for the stroke curve.